# Does my loop break because input(0) returns False?

Tags: c++, parameters, while-loop

I am trying to write a code for the game, rock-paper-scissors.

I recently just learned how to use a function to get user input and decided to try it here.

```
int getInput()
{
  int val;
  cin >> val; //only values from 0 to 2
  return val
}

int main() 
{
  int userChoice;
  while(userChoice = getInput()){//I get a warning here
   srand(time(NULL)); //always randon numbers
   int computer_choice = rand() % 3;
   switch(userChoice) {
      case:0
         //compare with computer_choice
         break;
      case:1
         //compare with computer_choice
         break;
      case:2
         //compare with computer_choice
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have two questions: 
Firstly, is using `userChoice = getInput()` as a parameter for my While Loop good practice? I am skeptical because of the warning I get which is this:

> suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

I believe this means, this parameter returns true. Using `while(true)` directly produces an infinite loop.
I want to keep the game going until the user decides to quit. I could easily have used `while(cin >> userChoice)` but like I mentioned earlier, I am looking to apply what I recently learned or is this just a case where directly using `while(cin >> userChoice)` is more pragmatic?

Secondly, the loop breaks when the `userChoice == 0` but other choices work. Is this because 0 returns false and so the while parameter is passed a `False` value and then breaks?

Thanks

Comment: Loop breaks because 0 is interpreted as false.

Comment: @KonstantinL, thanks, what about handling user input? what would you advice?

Comment: @OnomeSotu `while(userChoice = getInput())` is completely different from `while(cin >> userChoice)`, so choose whatever does what you want. First variant reads until you input `0`, while the other reads until `cin::operator bool` returns `false`.

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe since your second question has been asked and answered.  Your first question is primarily opinion based and and is a matter of style and how exactly you want to the code to flow.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I am learning. I wouldn't know what is opinion or style based except being told. Besides, I got a warning which prompted me to ask this question. If it was good practice, should I be getting a warning? Are there better options?

Comment: You get the warning because using `=` is normally a mistake.  In this case it is not and does what you think.  Typically you would rewrite it as `(userChoice = getInput()) == true` to express that you want to assign to a variable and test that it is true.  As far as a better option goes I would `while(cin >> userChoice)` unless you need some special handling like needing to limit the user input.

Comment: Thank you @NathanOliver. At least I understand why I get the warning.

Comment: Just for example: while( (userChoice = getInput()) <= 2 ){ - end the loop on an invalid input.